# How to apply selector on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `refresh()` function, set to be called periodically this way:

```
setInterval("refresh()", duration);
```

In this `refresh()` function, I am dynamically prepending content into a HTML table.

So I have this simple table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>original title</td><td>original date</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That becomes this new table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>new title</td><td>new date</td></tr>
        <tr><td>original title</td><td>original date</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Through the action of this `refresh()` function:

```
function refresh() {
    var lastDate = $('.myTableClass > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').first().text();

    $.get("./my_url.html?lastDate="+lastDate+, function (data) {
        if( data.trim().length > 0 ) {
            $(data).prependTo( $('.myTableClass > tbody') ).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
}
```

(The my_url.html page returns a simple `<tr>....</tr>` line.)

Everything works fine during the first call to `refresh()`, and new content is succesfully prepended to my table.

My problem is that after this first call, when there is no more new content to add, all the following calls to `refresh()` keep prepending the same content into my table.

So if I let the refresh being called 4 times, I am getting this table :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>new title</td><td>new date</td></tr>
        <tr><td>new title</td><td>new date</td></tr>
        <tr><td>new title</td><td>new date</td></tr>
        <tr><td>new title</td><td>new date</td></tr>
        <tr><td>original title</td><td>original date</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I found out that this happens because the `lastDate` var is never correctly updated with the new line's date, it always contains the date from the original first line.

What am I missing here? How can I get the new date from the ajax-prepended first `<tr>` line of my table ? Is the way I select `table > tbody > tr ...`  not compatible with ajax-loaded stuff?

[EDIT] If it's worth something, I am using jQuery 1.6.1.

Comment: Have you checked that the `lastDate` is what you expect, when you make a call to the ajax server? Do an alert() and see if you are loading it correctly.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes : as I said, the `lastDate` is wrong from the second call of `refresh()`, since it keeps getting the old line's date, and never gets the ajax-loaded new line's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the refresh function like this.

```
var lastDate = $('.myTableClass > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').first().text();
function refresh() {
    $.get("./my_url.html?lastDate="+lastDate+, function (data) {
        if( data.trim().length > 0 ) {
           $(data).prependTo( $('.myTableClass > tbody') ).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    }).done(function(){
        lastDate = $('.myTableClass > tbody > tr:first > td:nth-child(2)').text();
   });
}
```

You need to use done() function, which gets called after your ajax request is completed and it'll give you the latest date..

Comment: Si I need to make my `lastDate` var a global var, right?

Comment: Yes, make it global variable. call it before calling the function..
See my edited code..

Comment: It doesn't work: `lastDate` keep getting the old value, and never gets the ajax-prepended content's date value.

Comment: Ok, so the error was in your selector of done function.. I created the [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/QAnwkpnBuRd98DS8pTJ9?p=preview) for your reference. 
Also changed the above answer..

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I failed in my selector... Case solved!